# Bluetooth won't start - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, bluetooth, iphone, tethering

Some time ago I had my iPhone tethered via Bluetooth and saw the connection in Network Manager (the far right of the screen where the wireless icon is). Then it disappeared.

Now when I try to turn Bluetooth on, the button reverts to 'off' as soon as I change the screen to something else (by button I mean the slider where the word 'OFF' is in grey).

I've tried Blueman and updated Bluez to no avail. Bluetoothctl shows no response for `list` and `No default controller available` for `scan on`.

`rfkill list` shows:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I suspect the problem is with Bluetooth rather than Network Manager but I don't know how to get Bluetooth working. Any suggestions? It would be nice to use the iPhone as a backup connection if the wifi goes down but I need to tether it to the laptop.

The results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` are:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0408:5180 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The result of `dmesg | grep -i blu` is:

```
[   25.159919] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   25.159961] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   25.159969] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   25.159974] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   25.159984] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.205387] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   25.205392] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   25.217153] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[   25.218384] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[   25.218428] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 10, total size 33266
[   27.388090] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[   32.866481] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.866484] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.866492] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   35.548201] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
[ 4471.875676] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[ 4471.875681] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[ 4471.875689] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[ 4471.876514] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[ 4471.876641] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 10, total size 33266
[ 4474.033220] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[ 4482.257692] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
[ 6879.315868] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[ 6879.315874] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[ 6879.315951] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin
[ 6879.316873] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=2
[ 6879.316933] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 10, total size 33266
[ 6881.452952] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc20 tx timeout
[ 6889.676653] Bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: As an alternative, you can also tether to an iPhone through WiFi, and this is often faster than Bluetooth.

Comment: @Kurankat I did try this but each time I typed the password in on the laptop (the password shown on the iPhone), the computer told me the password was incorrect.

Comment: What is the kernel version? Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have also added this output. Thanks again for your help. The kernel is: 4.15.0-88-generic

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel 4.15 is too old for this hardware. Install HWE kernel by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```